# About a definition of an ordered pair $(a, b)$. To which set does $a$ belong?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am reading "Introduction to Set Theory" by Karel Hrbacek and Thomas Jech.

In this book, the definition of an ordered pair is this:

> Definition:
>   (a, b) := {{a}, {a, b}}.

The authors didn't write the set to which $a$ belongs.
The authors didn't write the set to which $b$ belongs.

Why?

In a more elementary set theory book, I found the following definition of an ordered pair:

> Definition:
>   Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets. For $a \in X$ and $b \in Y$, the ordered pair of $a$ and $b$ is defined as the set $\{a, \{a, b\}\}$.

Comment: What do you mean by "the set to which $a$ belongs"? Why is that relevant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're asking about why they said $a \in X, b \in Y$ in the second definition but not in the first definition. In fact, the definitions are equivalent and the choice is purely a matter of style. In particular, every object belongs to *some* set, so you could always in the first definition have said "let $A$ be a set containing $a$, and $B$ containing $b$, ...". But what difference would that have made?

To understand why the second author chose to include $a \in X$, $b \in Y$, we need to look *around* the definition. I would be willing to bet some money that in the second definition, the author talks about the Cartesian product $X \times Y$ somewhere nearby. This is so that they can efficiently write:

> Let $X$, $Y$ be two sets. The *Cartesian Product* is the set of all "ordered pairs", where:
>
> Def 1: (ordered pair), ...

In summary: It makes no mathematical difference whatsoever. $(a,b)$ is $(a,b)$ no matter where $a$ and $b$ 'come from'.

Comment: Thank you very much, preferred_anon.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can say that $a,b\in A$ for some set $A$.
Then $(a,b)$ is a subset of the power set of $A$ and so the pair is well-defined.

Comment: Thank you very much, Wuestenfux.